# Permission error while setting a local nominatim sever

Tags: ubuntu, server, openstreetmap, geocoding, nominatim

I have been following the [official documentation](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Installation/) to create a local server. However each time I try to import the osm data to the postgres server I am being returned an error that says permission denied even though all other groups have read permissions. [image]

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/srv/nominatim/build/module/nominatim.so'
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run the import as user "postgres" but as user "nominatim" to import data.